# Finding a volume of region $-\frac{10}{9}\geq \sum_{1\leq k < l\leq 4}\cos(\theta_k-\theta_l)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume, surface-integrals

I am interested in finding a volume given by variables $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3, \theta_4 \in [0, 2\pi]$ for which we have a region defined by
$$ -\frac{10}{9} \geq \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2) + \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_3) + \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_4) + \cos(\theta_2 - \theta_3) + \cos(\theta_2 - \theta_4) + \cos(\theta_3 - \theta_4) \:.$$

I posted a similar question previously [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4786826/finding-a-volume-of-region-0-geq-cos-theta-1-theta-2-cos-theta-1) for n=3, this question is for case n=4. I am also interested if there is a more general approach to this problem as the dimensionality increases.

I will calculate more precision numerical integration so far I have

```
NIntegrate[
 Boole[0 >= 
   Cos[x1 - x2] + Cos[x1 - x3] + Cos[x1 - x4] + Cos[x2 - x3] + 
    Cos[x2 - x4] + Cos[x3 - x4]], {x1, 0, 2*Pi}, {x2, 0, 2*Pi}, {x3, 
  0, 2*Pi}, {x4, 0, 2*Pi}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

which gives me `957.74`.